# Binary Search and duplicates

Tags: search, theory, binary-search

Let's say we an array {–2, 8, 13, 22, 25, 25, 38, 42, 51, 103}

When a binary search splits it in 2 the first time, what will be considered the middle value?

My own guess is the second value named 25, because only then the search knows that it's identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it always tries to find the middle by

```
(0+n)/2 = (0+9)/2 = 4(Integer)
```

In your case.

So in case you want to search 25 itself, as per the algorithm you will find in the lower bound group, position 4 first as a match.

Answer (score 1):

The middle value is first 25 number.

Your binarySearch first call is something like that : binarySearch(a,1,a.length) , where "a" is your array.

Your array length is 10 , so m = ((10-1) +1)/2 = 5 position in array .

Then you call binarySearch(1,m) and apply the same method to this array (the first half from orginal array )
–2, 8, 13, 22, 25

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. What exactly is the +1 in m = ((10-1) +1)/2?

Comment: It's mathematics. To find the lentgh from a to b you do (b-a) +1 . For example , your array length is 10 . First element is on first position ( a = 1 ) and last element is on 10 position , so length is 10-1+1 = 10

Comment: Another example : m = 5 , so binarySearch call for the second half of your array is binarySearch(a,m+1,a.length) = binarySearch(a,6,10) and this call will work on this array {25 , 38 , 42 , 51 , 103}; to find the m for this half of your array you must know the lentgh of this ( who is 5 , but you must to find out ) : 10-6+1 =5 and m will be 5/2 =2